# angular why collection isn't rendering in template

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive

I would like to know why my collection of persons isn't rendering in this directive:

http://codepen.io/agustincba/pen/vgOLVV

```
modulo.directive('personRenderer', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:  `
        <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <td>Nombre</td>
                  <td>DNI</td>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

              <tr ng-repeat="person in personas">
                  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{person.dni}}</td>  
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    `,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      personas: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope)
    {
      console.log($scope.personas);
    }
  }
```

});

thankx... I made a controller (which I removed) and it was logging all the people... It's weird...

Answer (score 1):

Please review I just remove {{}} bracket from person-renderer and it works

```
<div ng-app="CholoApp">
  <div ng-controller="CholoController">

    <person-renderer personas="items"></person-renderer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dipak. Thankx a lot for your help !.